# Meaning of the words GONNA NEED in the clause

Tags: meaning-in-context

What do the words in bold mean?
what's the difference between these two clauses?

We're **GONNA NEED** you.

We'll need you.

Comment: gonna is going to. And it's a way to imitate in writing people speaking fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Gonna" (used in the present progressive such as "I'm gonna" or "he's gonna") is an informal way to establish the future tense.

It is essentially equivalent to "will".

There is no difference in meaning between your two example sentences, but the one using "gonna" is more informal. You should not use "gonna" in an academic paper, for example.